# OnClick of link Button webgrid rows getting cleared

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on VB.Net, ASP.NET. I have a web form with link button and intersoft grid. OnClick of the link button. I'm opening the popup window. The Problem I'm facing is when I click the link button all the rows in web grid(intersoft) are getting cleared. Can any one help me? what might be the problem.

This is my link button code to open popup. onclick of this button all the rows in the grid are getting cleared.

```
Protected Sub lnkBtnProfile_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim Empno As String
    Empno = e.CommandArgument
    sb.Append("<script>")
    sb.Append("window.open('Profile.aspx','name','width=750,height=300,menubar=no,to‌​olbar=no,help=no,status=no,resizable=0')")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    Me.RegisterStartupScript("OpenPopUp", sb.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to show some of your code in order for us to help you.

Comment: Protected Sub lnkBtnProfile_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs) Dim sb As New StringBuilder Dim Empno As String Empno = e.CommandArgument sb.Append("<script>") sb.Append("window.open('Profile.aspx','name','width=750,height=300,menubar=no,toolbar=no,help=no,status=no,resizable=0')") sb.Append("</script>") Me.RegisterStartupScript("OpenPopUp", sb.ToString()) End Sub                                                                     This is my link button code  to open popup.  onclick of this button all the rows in the grid are getting cleared.

Comment: I don't know what the specific problem is, but I do know from extensive experience that intersoft is very tricky to get configured correctly since they perform a lot of actions on postbacks. I believe that the issue is probably that you are not rebinding intersoft on a postback or that one of the many variations in settings for how the grid is to manage the data is not set quite right. Sorry I can't be more specific, but we have > 3000 LOC dealing with the intricacies of intersoft.

Comment: I figured out the problem and it is also the part of your answer. The link button is causing a postback and I'm losing the data. In order to avoid it I'm using the hyperlink. Is ther any other way to do : To provide a link and onclick opening pop up from server side.

Comment: I have added an answer that incorporates some of my comments above and shows how you should be able to do this on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the specific problem is, but I do know from extensive experience that intersoft is very tricky to get configured correctly since they perform a lot of actions on postbacks.

I believe that the issue is probably that you are not rebinding intersoft on a postback or that one of the many variations in settings for how the grid is to manage the data is not set quite right.

However, I don't think that you need to postback in order to perform the operation as shown in your code. You should be able to create a javascript function with this information and call it directly on the client side.

Something like:

```
<script>
  function OpenProfile(empNo) {
    window.open('Profile.aspx?empNo=' + empNo,'_blank','width=750,height=300,menubar=no,to‌​olbar=no,help=no,status=no,resizable=0');
  }
</script>
```